# Path mapping in tsconfig is interpreted as an external module

Tags: angular, typescript

(context : angular 8, node 12.15.0)

**EDIT** : It seems to be a bug so I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35499)

I am building a library. I defined the path `@env` in `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    [...]
    "paths": {
      "@env/*": [
        "projects/mylib/src/environments/*"
      ]
    }
}
```

And in the code, I reference the environment like this :

```
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
```

But it seems that the compiler is misled because when I try to build (`ng build my-lib`), I get the following warning :

`WARNING: No name was provided for external module '@env/environment' in output.globals – guessing 'environment'`

Also, importing the module in a project generates this error message at compilation :

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "my-lib" has missing dependencies:
 - @env/environment
```

It seems that `@env/environment` is interpreted as an external module. How can I avoid that ?

**Steps to reproduce :**

*Note : I made a ready-to-use SSCCE [here](https://github.com/ArnaudDenoyelle/sscce-angular9-paths)*

1. Create a new project (`ng new acme`) with simplest options : no routing, plain old CSS for style.
2. In the project, create a library (`ng g generate library my-lib`)
3. under `projects/my-lib/src`, create a folder `environments` with 2 files: `environment.ts` and `environments.prod.ts`
4. Configure `projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json` like this (I just added the `paths` block):

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "baseUrl": [ "./" ],
      "@env/*": [ "projects/my-lib/src/environments/*" ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
}
```

Project should look like this :

```
.
├── angular.json
├── browserslist
├── e2e
│   ├── protractor.conf.js
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── app.e2e-spec.ts
│   │   └── app.po.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── karma.conf.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── projects
│   └── my-lib
│       ├── karma.conf.js
│       ├── ng-package.json
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── src
│       │   ├── environments
│       │   │   ├── environment.prod.ts
│       │   │   └── environment.ts
│       │   ├── lib
│       │   │   ├── my-lib.component.spec.ts
│       │   │   ├── my-lib.component.ts
│       │   │   ├── my-lib.module.ts
│       │   │   ├── my-lib.service.spec.ts
│       │   │   └── my-lib.service.ts
│       │   ├── public-api.ts
│       │   └── test.ts
│       ├── tsconfig.lib.json
│       ├── tsconfig.lib.prod.json
│       ├── tsconfig.spec.json
│       └── tslint.json
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.component.css
│   │   ├── app.component.html
│   │   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   └── app.module.ts
│   ├── assets
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── environment.prod.ts
│   │   └── environment.ts
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── polyfills.ts
│   ├── styles.css
│   └── test.ts
├── tsconfig.app.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.spec.json
└── tslint.json
```

Now,

- to reproduce the warning, build the library : `ng build my-lib`
- to reproduce the error, import `MyLibModule` in the main project and build it : `ng build`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the response I got from the angular maintainers [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35499) :

> Its not recommended to use path mappings for libraries.

And also :

> path mappings in a library were never supported, and shouldn’t have ever worked and in your case it seems that they worked because of ts configuration leaking from the library to your application.

So, the conclusion is : **DO NOT** use path mappings in libraries.

Comment: anyone know of any replacements for the same functionality?